# How to submit a GET and PUT request in C#? Have already done so via PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, vpn, put

I'm venturing out from my PowerShell cave and have started dabbling in C# (Due in main part to most people telling me it's a great stepping stone). I've managed to convert most of my existing scripts to C# but am running into some trouble now. I've got the below (in PowerShell) which uses an API Key and URI to do a GET Request and then use that same API key and URI to do a PUT.

Before that though, it gets the hostname and the VPN address, uses the former in the GET request and the latter in the PUT Request.

```
$Computer = Hostname

$VpnIpAddress = Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4 -InterfaceAlias MyVPN | select IPAddress -expandproperty IPAddress

$APIKey = 'MyApi'
$EncodedCredentials = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(('{0}:{1}' -f $APIKey, $null)))
$Header = @{}
$Header.Add('Authorization', ('Basic {0}' -f $EncodedCredentials))

$URI = "MyApiUri/$Computer"

$DisplayID = Invoke-RestMethod -URI $URI -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json" -Method Get | Select Assets -expandproperty Assets | select display_id -expandproperty display_id

$parameters = @{

        FieldName1 = @{                 
            FieldName2 = @{
                FieldName3 = "$VpnIpAddress"
            }
        }
    }
    
$Result = invoke-RestMethod -URI "MyApiUri/$DisplayID" -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/json" -Method PUT -Body (ConvertTo-Json $parameters)
```

I know I can get the Hostname using `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME");` and that's pretty much it. I'm not sure how to get the VPN address nor do I know how to submit a GET or PUT. I've has some luck following guides online on how to submit if there **isn't** a key but it seems that mee needing a key screws things up.

Any advice?

Comment: [HttpClient](https://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient) is your friend, along with `NetworkAdapter`. A tutorial is out of scope for [se] websites, in paricular [so]. If you have a specific question about some specific code then please update. For further help